# ¿ Donde puedo mirar la id de mi server en openstack?

Tags: api

Tengo que meter el siguiente código para ver las métricas de mi server openstack:

```
curl -H "X-Subject-Token: 3939c299ba0743eb94b6f4ff6ff97f6d" http://controller:8774/v2.1/<tenant-id>/servers/<server-id>/diagnostics
```

¿Donde puedo encontrar la id del server?,he visto que puedo crear un grupo de servers y tiene id pero no se si es eso. Me da error :
{"error": {"message": "The request you have made requires authentication.", "code": 401, "title": "Unauthorized"}}

Answer (score 0):

De hecho el `{server_id}` debe ser uno dentro de una lista de servidores, puedes obtener el id del servidor y otras propiedas de esta forma usando el sdk

```
from credentials import get_nova_credentials_v2
from novaclient.client import Client
from utils import print_server

def print_server(server):
    print("-"*35)
    print("server id: %s" % server.id)
    print("server name: %s" % server.name)
    print("server image: %s" % server.image)
    print("server flavor: %s" % server.flavor)
    print("server key name: %s" % server.key_name)
    print("user_id: %s" % server.user_id)
    print("-"*35)
```

Revisa la [documentaciòn](https://docs.openstack.org/mitaka/user-guide/sdk_compute_apis.html).

Answer (score 0):

También usando el propio comando de openstack que te lo devuelve: [openstack server list](https://docs.openstack.org/python-openstackclient/pike/cli/command-objects/server.html#server-list)

```
$ openstack server list
+------------------+----------------------+--------+------------+-------------+------------------+------------+
| ID               | Name                 | Status | Task State | Power State | Networks         | Image Name |
+------------------+----------------------+--------+------------+-------------+------------------+------------+
| 7e3251e-91873... | stackoverflow-exampl | ACTIVE | None       | Running     | private=10.0.0.2 | cirros     |
+------------------+----------------------+--------+------------+-------------+------------------+------------
```

Con esto listarás las instancias creadas en el componente `nova`.